# Dataframe Standard Deviation issue due to a single column of text

Tags: python, pandas, standard-deviation

I have a dataframe to that have rows of survey response values (1 - 5) which I'm trying to get a standard deviation for.

The final column indicates which survey group the data belongs to (column name = Respondants).  Because these columns have text instead of an integer, standard deviation returns NaN.  skipna=True doesn't work in this scenario.  I need to keep that column as the analysis will compare the responses from each group in a single scatterplot.  I can't seem to find a way that I can get the standard deviation to ignore that column.  I don't want to delete the column for the aforementioned reasons.

The code being used is:

```
df1['std dev']=df.std(skipna=True)
df1.head()
```

I'm not sure what I can add to ignore the column "Respondants" for the std.

EDIT

I found a workaround, wasn't ideal, but it did the job.

I split my data into 2 Excel sheets, dropped the offending column in each.  Then performed my standard deviations, added the "Respondants" columns back into each dataframe and merged them into a new DF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`df.iloc[:, :-1].std()`

In english, this means use all rows, and use all but the last column.

If you want a standard deviations per row, then you will need:

`df.iloc[:, :-1].std(axis=1)`

Comment: Legend mate. I will try that now.

Comment: OK, this is really odd.  If I do `display (df.iloc[:, :-2])`, it does it perfectly.  However, if I try `df.iloc[:, :-2].std()` nothing changes.  Still shows the dataframe as it was.

Comment: You probably need to provide a more detailed description of what you have and want.

Comment: Completely understandable.  I actually think that what I wanted just wasn't going to work, so I worked around it.  I split my excel sheet into 2, dropped the Respondants column, added the standard deviation, added in the Respondants columns to both DFs and merged into a new DF.  Job's a goodun!  Thanks for help though.